# Exception using EF Core 1 RC2: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a new ASP.NET Core 1 RC2 application. (Visual Studio, IIS Express). It has both authentication and data in the same database (at least for now):

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationIdentityContext>(options =>
  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

I can see that Identity part works (if I "Register", a record is created in AspNetUsers table). However, any attempts to get the data through MyDbContext are throwing an error

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

For `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms` Nuget gives me a choice of 4.1.0-rc2 and 4.0.0-beta. Both throw the same error

From some other places I found advice to install `System.Net.Security`, `Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms` - but it doesn't help, either